# Как лучше спроектировать и реализовать корпоративную систему ведения заметок?

Tags: reactjs, проектирование, nestjs

Нужно реализовать web-приложение, в котором пользователи локальной сети могут создавать свои заметки, давать доступ к заметке другим пользователям.

Заметки должны храниться в формате markdown. Приложение должно работать только в локальной сети, исключая доступ в интернет.

Я выделил 2 сущности, User и Note с полями:

User:
-id
-username
-password
-createdAt
-updatedAt

Note:
-id
-type (enum: private/public)
-pathToFile
-authorId

Связь many-to-many, поэтому я сделал промежуточную таблицу где соотносятся id юзера и заметки.

Правильный ли это подход? И как работать с markdown файлами? Правильно ли хранить в БД путь к самому файлу, а сам файл где-то на сервере.
Какие технологии использовать, чтобы прикрутить редактирование markdown файла в самом приложении?
Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь автоматически авторизовывался, после того как залогинился в свою учетку компа?

Я использую nest js для бека, react для фронта. БД - постгрес.

Спасибо